# How to rotate UIView using transform?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, transform, core-motion

I have a `UIView` which I am trying to transform (rotate) using the pitch value you can get from coremotion attitude. I am using transform however I am not sure my code is correct as the `UIView` is not doing anything.

This is my code its being called several times per second.

```
- (void)setLabelValueRoll:(double)roll pitch:(double)pitch yaw:(double)yaw
{
    self.yLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"pitch: %f", pitch];


    CATransform3D transform;
    transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(pitch + M_PI_2, 1, 0, 0);
    self.wapaA.layer.sublayerTransform = transform;
}
```

I am not sure how to set this part **(pitch + M_PI_2, 1, 0, 0)** to make the pitch affect my square `UIView` so it would I guess stay level as you tilt the phone back and forth.

Comment: If wapaA is the UIView, then just applying wapaA.transform should work

Comment: If i do that I get a warning **Property access result unused - getters should not be used for side effects** nore dose it work unfortunatly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `layer's transform property` of `UIView`

```
wapaA.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(pitch + M_PI_2, 1, 0, 0);
```

Comment: great! that worked.. thanks for that I ended up changing the calculation to get the effect i want  **(pitch + M_PI_2, 0, 0, 1)**

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
float degrees = 20; //the value in degrees
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degrees * M_PI/180);
```