# Transform specific segment in segmented control

Tags: swift, transform, uisegmentedcontrol

Is there a way to transform the content of a specific segment contained in segmented control? (I have to rotate it by 180deg)

Not the image contained in it, because in my case there isn't one (I have used FontAwesome)

Demonstration:

from: [image: original] to: [image: rotated]

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is!

Consider that we have a segmented control contains 3 segments:

[image]

Actually, it is a view which contains 3 `subviews`, typed as `UISegment`. If we try to print this segmented control [subviews](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622614-subviews) (Assuming that we connected it to the desired view controller as `segmentedControl` IBOutlet):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // MARK:- IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for view in segmentedControl.subviews {
            print(view)
        }
    }
}
```

The log should display something similar to:

> UISegment: 0x7febebc06980; frame = (229 0; 114 29); layer = CALayer:
>   0x60000002edc0
>   UISegment: 0x7febebe140c0; frame = (114 0; 114 29); layer = CALayer: 0x618000231800
>   UISegment: 0x7febebe14d30; frame = (0 0; 113 29); layer = CALayer: 0x6180002319c0

So, you can access the segments in the segmented control as a `UISegment`, thus apply needed edit to it as a UIView. For instance, if you want to rotate the second segment, you could implement:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for view in segmentedControl.subviews[1].subviews {
        print(view)
        view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)
    }
}
```

As you can see, the segment also has subviews:

> UISegmentLabel: 0x7f8b51701770; frame = (0 0; 64 22.5); text =
>   'Second'; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer =
>   _UILabelLayer: 0x610000091530
>
> UIImageView: 0x7f8b51701470; frame = (114 0; 1 1); alpha = 0; opaque =
>   NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = -1030; layer =
>   CALayer: 0x610000031480

So, you should rotate all of these subviews, as implemented in above the code snippet.

The output would be:

[image]

The same approach should be applicable with segmented controls that have images instead of titles:

Before rotating:

[image]

After rotating:

[image]

Comment: Could you mention what is the problem? have you tried to print the subviews of a segmented control as mentioned in the answer? I think that you might miss something...

Comment: it's printing pretty the same, but the view isn't changing.

Comment: If it prints the same (it contains subviews of UISegment), then it should works fine... If you think that there is a specific part of the mentioned code is not working, please tell me about it. I might create a repo and share it...

Comment: In iOS 13, I am experiencing a bug that causes subviews to return 3 instances of UISegment, as well as 3 instances of UIImageView. So there are 6 subviews in total. It's making it difficult to access the UISegments as UISegment is private.

Answer (score 1):

A segment is a small UIView, you can just apply a transformation to it.

Refer to this question about getting the subview:

[UISegmentedControl selected segment color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270526/uisegmentedcontrol-selected-segment-color)

And refer to this other one to "rotate" the content.

[How to rotate UIView using transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443802/how-to-rotate-uiview-using-transform)

Then again, i'd just be easier to make an image out of it and use that instead.

Comment: Thanks @Pochi. However when the whole UIView is being mirrored, some other properties are flipped too, like those rounded borders. I have edit the question now - asking for flipping UIView's content and not the UIView itself. P.S.: UIView doesn't contain a UILabel. It contains a thing called UISegmentLabel.